# How can I translate these openvpn client configuration instructions to work with Fedora 20?

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, fedora, openvpn

Here's the [link](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/09/openvpn-setup/) to the full instructions.

When I get to step 9, under the heading "9. Setup Client Config Files", it says:

> Now we will configure the openVPN to
>   work as client. Remember that we have
>   already installed the openvpn package
>   in client, and we have “ca.crt”,
>   “vpnclient1.key”, vpnclient1.crt” in
>   /etc/openvpn/
>
> Copy the sample client.conf to
>   /etc/openvpn.
>
> $ sudo cp
>   /usr/share/doc/openvpn/examples/sample-config-files/client.conf
>   /etc/openvpn/
>
> Edit the /etc/openvpn/client.conf.
>
> ...
>
> ## Specify that this is openvpn client client
>
> remote vpnserver 1194
>
> ca ca.crt
>
> cert vpnclient1.crt
>
> key vpnclient1.key ...
>
> Now start the OpenVPN in client
>
> $ /etc/init.d/openvpn start  *
>   Starting virtual private network
>   daemon(s)...   * Autostarting VPN
>   'client'
>
> $ ifconfig tun0 tun0      Link
>   encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr
>   00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
>
> ```
>       inet addr:10.8.0.6  P-t-P:10.8.0.5  Mask:255.255.255.255
> ```

However, when I try to run that last command, I get the following error:

```
bash: /etc/init.d/openvpn: No such file or directory
```

I assumed that the script got subsumed by systemctl or something, so I then tried the next few:

```
# systemctl enable openvpn@.service 
# systemctl start openvpn@.service
```

...which I stumbled on through tab completion. Can anyone shed any light on how to proceed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To start an OpenVPN connection defined by `foo.conf` in `/etc/openvn` on a modern Fedora system you want to use `systemctl start openvpn@foo.service` and you can enable it for future boots with `systemctl enable openvpn@foo.service`.

A systemd unit of the form `name@.service` is a template unit, and you need to specify which specific instance of the unit you want to work with - in the case of OpenVPN the instance name is the basename of the configuration file.

So in your case you can start the connection with:

```
systemctl start openvpn@client.service
```

and enable it permanently wih:

```
systemctl enable openvpn@client.service
```